# How to automatically create variables sampled from a normal distribution and specifying specific n

Tags: r, statistics

So I'm trying to simulate some data. What I'm basically doing simulating n normally distributed data from a sequence of numbers with the mean varying. Afterward, I group these numbers into one single matrix and then I take the mean of randomly sampled numbers from this group. What I'm trying to see is what happens to the mean as n increases, however, I only know how to do this manually, in this code example I did it first with n=3 then with n=5. I would like to be able to specify a specific and very large n.

```
#A person has a favorable attitude from -10 to 10. -10 being absolutely bad and 10 being absolutely good
x <- seq(-10, 10, by = .1)

#lets assume people people holds  attitude towards a concept. Assume each concepts attitude means distribute normal.

y<-dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)
y2<-dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)
y3<-dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)
attitudes_list<-c(y,y2,y3)
attitudes_single<-mean(sample(attitudes_list, 1))
attitudes2<-mean(sample(attitudes_list, 2))
attitudes3<-mean(sample(attitudes_list, 3))

attitudes<-as.data.frame(c(attitudes_single, attitudes2, attitudes3))
colnames(attitudes)<-c("mean")
ggplot(attitudes, aes(x=mean)) +
geom_histogram( )

#as n increases the probability of the mean of the sequence of attitudes goes to 0
y<-dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)
y2<-dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)
y3<-dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)
y4<-dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)
y5<-dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)
attitudes_list<-c(y,y2,y3, y4, y5)
attitudes_single<-mean(sample(attitudes_list, 1))
attitudes2<-mean(sample(attitudes_list, 2))
attitudes3<-mean(sample(attitudes_list, 3))
attitudes4<-mean(sample(attitudes_list, 4))
attitudes5<-mean(sample(attitudes_list, 5))
```

Comment: If you trying to generate random normals, why not use `rnorm()`?  `dnorm()` evaluates the normal PDF with respect to `x`.  Plus, I don't think `sample()` is specified correctly because `sample(x, 1, .7)` treats .7 as the argument to `replace`, which expects a logical value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).  Also, I'm not sure what you get by taking the mean of a single sampled value.

Comment: Because Im creating a normal distribution from which to sample from. When I use the sample function I specify from where I want to sample, what the mean is and the .7 should be the sd from what I understand. I'm trying to prove what happens if you take the mean of one sampled value, then two, then three, etc.

Comment: In your code `dnorm(x, sample(x, 1, .7), .7)`, the first .7 is the argument given to `replace` in the `sample()` function.  The second .7 is, indeed, the mean of the normal function.  However, let's say that the mean you use is 0, `dnorm(x, 0, .7)` is itself nor normally distributed.  To convince yourself, do `hist(dnorm(x, 0, .7))`.  It will show a heavily right-skewed distribution.  If you want a variable that will be normally distributed, `rnorm()` will produce random variates from a normal distribution.